# how to render rich-text contentful

Tags: ruby, contentful

I have a field Rich text in contentful that I try to render, it's a ordered list. 
I installed the gem rich-text-renderer [ https://github.com/contentful/rich-text-renderer.rb ] but I don't get how to render the Rich text, is anyone having an example, a tuto or could help me on this point ?

In my view I call the field like this :

```
<% tools = contentful.entries(content_type:'tools',include: 2)%>
```

but can't display the field called test in the right way

Answer (score 0):

Install Contentful Rich Text Renderer

```
gem 'rich_text_renderer', '~> 0.2.1'
```

Run

```
bundle install
```

Create a renderer in your Controller

```
@renderer = RichTextRenderer::Renderer.new
```

Then use it in your view

```
<% tools = contentful.entries(content_type:'tools', include: 2)%>
<% tools.each do |tool| %>
  <div class="contentful_product">
    <h1><%= tool.title %></h1>
    <%= @renderer.render(tool.description).html_safe %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```